# Python Scrapy keeps returning "Invalid Syntax"

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new to scrapy, today is my first day even looking at it. I am running into a problem with the most basic code. I keep getting an error saying `invalid syntax`. Here is my code and below that is the error I am getting. I am running this in the terminal, and not python itself.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://toscrape.com/random']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)

2018-09-11 18:30:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-09-11 18:30:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-09-11 18:30:29 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/runspider.py", line 88, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spidercls, **opts.spargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 170, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 198, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 203, in _create_crawler
    return Crawler(spidercls, self.settings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.extensions = ExtensionManager.from_crawler(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/telnet.py", line 12, in <module>
    from twisted.conch import manhole, telnet
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/conch/manhole.py", line 154
    def write(self, data, async=False):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Perhaps check this out: [Github website](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143)

Comment: @JoeA Takes me to Github with nothing there?

Comment: It should be this link: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143

Comment: @JoeA You've got the answer.Post it as the answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Seems that you need to have either version 3.6 installed or edit the a file.

Comment: That makes sense I'm happy to help you find the right resource with the answer!

Answer (score 1):

async is a keyword of Python > 3.4.
You have to check your python version and the library is supported your python version.

Comment: checked and I am running python3.7

Comment: I think it may work for you; use _async as the variable name instead async (manhole.py, line 154)

Comment: I used isAsync instead.